# Define partial views on a SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

We are dealing with a very large legacy SQLAlchemy model (and underlying table schema) aggregating many logically-separate models, that cannot, for practical reasons, be refactored.

We would want to be able to design authorizations/permissions on sub-models that restrict read/write to a subset of attributes (and perhaps methods as well).

What would be the best approach to design a "partial view" Mixin/Class/Metaclass that would allow:

1. keeping the same original SQLAlchemy/flask-sqlalchemy model underneath (support `.query` etc)
2. once loaded/inited, restrict access to a designated subset (stored at class level) of attributes

In essence going from:

```
class MyLargeModel(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   foo = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
   bar = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
   baz = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

To something like:

```
class ModelBase(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class FooView(ModelBase):
   foo = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
   [??]

class BarView(ModelBase):
   bar = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
   [??]

class BarbazView(BarView):
   baz = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
   [??]

class MyLargeModel(FooView, BarbazView):
   [??]
```

Where each of the view class retain as much of the SQLA model properties as possible (loading, and ideally persisting).

In a way, something similar to what SQLA-Marshmallow etc do for schemas (except while keeping an actual ORM model).

Is there any known pattern that could help me here?

[Edit] After further digging, it *seems* like SQLAlchemy's [Single table inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) might hold the key to what we are trying to do, but it seems to require a `polymorphic_on` column to split vertically on (I only want to split horizontally).

Comment: Are you pinned to a certain SQLAlchemy version?

Comment: Not really. Currently using the 2.x.

Comment: I posted a sort of answer.  I think maybe the ORM attribute event system could help too but what is the purpose of this restriction?  Are you trying to limit the access of actual users?

Comment: Also can objects still be created with the restricted columns/attributes?  In my example I used a postal column, would you still want to be able to do `Address(..., postal=something)` ?

Comment: And another question, when you say the model is legacy but you are using 2.x, did you mean the database design itself is legacy or the codebase interacting with the ORM models is legacy or ?  What part is the legacy part?

Comment: @IanWilson added a pseudocode illustration that hopefully makes the goal clearer.

Ideally would want loading and persistence to work on subset classes, could live without creation (having to use the full class for that).

"Legacy" in that the DB schema can't move, and ideally the code is backward compatible (the full-set model class still behaves as expected)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I finally found a solution that, while not extremely satisfying (it relies on a fairly ugly `__table__` definition) seems to fit my bill exactly.

Sharing for any future searches:

```
from redatabase.database import db
from redatabase.models import ValuationRequest
    
from sqlalchemy.orm.relationships import RelationshipProperty

class ModelViewMeta(type(db.Model)):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        parent_model = attrs.get('_' + name + '__parent_model', None)
        included_attributes = attrs.get('_' + name + '__included_attributes', [])
        if parent_model:
            attrs['__table__'] = parent_model.__table__.select().with_only_columns([
                    getattr(parent_model, attribute) for attribute in included_attributes
                    if not isinstance(getattr(parent_model, attribute).property, RelationshipProperty)
                ]).subquery()
            for attribute in included_attributes:
                attrs[attribute] = getattr(parent_model, attribute)
        else:
            attrs['__abstract__'] = True
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

class ModelView(db.Model, metaclass=ModelViewMeta):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)


class FooModelView(ModelView):
    __parent_model = OriginalModel
    __included_attributes = ['id', 'foo']
```

The class `FooModelView` above will correctly expose only `__included_attributes` while still keeping all the properties expected from a SQLAlchemy model.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to configure the mappers to include or exclude certain attributes as described here:
[mapping-a-subset-of-table-columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-a-subset-of-table-columns)

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    Table,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, update, insert, delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload
from sqlalchemy import event

Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


users_t = Table('users', Base.metadata, *[
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String),
])


class User(Base):
    __table__ = users_t
    #whitelist
    __mapper_args__ = {"include_properties": ["id", "name"]}
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")


addresses_t = Table('addresses', Base.metadata, *[
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String),
    Column("postal", String),
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False),
])

class Address(Base):
    __table__ = addresses_t
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")
    #blacklist
    __mapper_args__ = {"exclude_properties": ["postal"]}


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    u1 = User(name="user1", addresses=[Address(name="user1_home")])
    session.add(u1)
    session.commit()


TEST_POSTAL = '93442'

# Not there with orm but try to set attr anyways.
with Session(engine) as session:
    users = session.scalars(select(User)).all()
    assert len(users[0].addresses) == 1
    try:
        postal = users[0].postal
    except AttributeError:
        print ("No postal address")
    users[0].postal = TEST_POSTAL
    session.commit()


# Still not there with orm.
with Session(engine) as session:
    users = session.scalars(select(User)).all()
    assert len(users[0].addresses) == 1
    try:
        postal = users[0].addresses[0].postal
    except AttributeError:
        print ("No postal address")


# Set with core.
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(update(Address.__table__).values(postal=TEST_POSTAL))
    session.commit()

# Still not there with orm.
with Session(engine) as session:
    users = session.scalars(select(User)).all()
    assert len(users[0].addresses) == 1
    try:
        postal = users[0].addresses[0].postal
    except AttributeError:
        print ("No postal address")

# Is there with core.
with Session(engine) as session:
    postals = session.scalars(select(Address.__table__.c.postal)).all()
    assert postals == [TEST_POSTAL]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab. I have edited my question to add a concrete code example which might help.
Not entirely sure about the finality of some of the code above (perhaps a more reduced example with only `Address` would be useful), but "include_properties" might be something to explore.
In the code above, I'm not sure how I would go about having a `AddressWithPostal` class in addition to the base `Address` class…

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand the subclass thing.  I thought you were somehow trying to replace existing classes with new limits.  If it is new code over an old db schema can't you just put the data access behind a service layer and sort this out there?

Comment: the main goal is to avoid creating a new incompatible layer (which would require refactor all existing code) and instead use SQLA to split the tables into submodels…